# Serving large files in AWS

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, nas

As part of a big system, I'm trying to implement a service that (among other tasks) will serve large files (up to 300MB) to other servers (running in Amazon).

This files service needs to have more than one machine up and running at each time, and there are also multiple clients.

Service is written in Python, using Tornado web server.
First approach was using MySQL, but I figured I'm going to have hell saving such big BLOBs, because of memory consumption.

Tried to look at Amazon's EFS, but it's not available in our region.

I heard about SoftNAS, and am currently looking into it.

Any other good alternatives I should be checking?

Comment: What about a NoSQL data store like Cassandra?  On AWS writing the blobs would be very fast, and reading could be fast too depending on how you structure it.

Comment: Wondering if it's not an overkill, but I'll look into it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Why not dynamoDB + S3?

Comment: Generally my approach here would be to store references in a database to files that are on S3.

Comment: Saving in S3 would require either having the files public, or having the client authenticate, no option for subnet validation, right?

Answer (score 0):

You also can use MongoDb , it provides several API, and also you can store file in S3 bucket with the use of Multi-Part Upload

Comment: Thanks, but we've had such a bad experience with mongodb, that even by mentioning it, I will be shot...